# Xamarin Forms debug errors

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I get this error when i try to debug  Xamarin android Application
Error       ADB0010: Unexpected install output: cmd: Can't find service: package

I was using Android Pie , the only thing that worked is that i started to use Android Oreo images to debug . 
Is there any way to make Android Pie work ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to reinstall the Pie android simulator.

Comment: tried that over 15 times . tried different sorts of emulators .

Comment: Have you tried to run a new project on the Pie simulator?

Comment: yes , File New , totally fresh project .

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your simulators. Create two simulators. First one with Oreo and second one with Pie. Solution here is to reinstall for same project.

Comment: Are you using VS 2019 ?

Comment: Seems like there is a bug with Android Pie Emulator and VS 2019 ... for now you are limited to Oreo. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482602/xamarin-failed-to-deploy-app-to-emulator-with-unexpected-install-output-cmd

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57353168/2987314) worked for me. Another thing I had to do after deploying the app was changing the target/minimum Android version to match the emulator's version:

[image]