# Why does my Android App freeze and can't deploy?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

I am using a MAC Book Pro and I wrote my Android App in Visual Studio using Xamarin in Parallels (virtual machine).

When starting the app, it builds, but then the "mobile screen" freezes and when I stop the application then I get two Error Messages:

-) Error ADB0010: Unexpected install output: cmd: Can't find service: package

-) Error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: cmd: Can't find service: package

How can I fix this?

[The App looks like this when I've started it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kedsx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below suggestions:

1. Make sure you have the latest Android Emulator version running.
2. Try a different Android version `If you're using Visual Studio 2019 like me you have to go with Android 8.1 Oreo or higher.`
   3.Read this: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482602/xamarin-failed-to-deploy-app-to-emulator-with-unexpected-install-output-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It normally caused by that the android emulator does not run well. Please check that you have installed all the emulator package.

After that, when I get this issue, I always stop the android device, in the device manager, edit to change the disk.dataPartition.size value to ‘5000M’(You could set the value according to your device.).

[image]