# Xamarin forms app fails to deploy to Android 10 real device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono, android-10.0

#### Description

I have a project that runs fine on my Nokia android device. To update its reach, I updated my device to android 10. I went to the SDK manager and got the android v29.

With my AMD PC, a debug only using real devices.

I changed the target framework to v29, Android 10-Q.

I am getting deployment issues

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a Xamarin. Forms project that targets Android 9.
2. Update framework and Nugget package to update
3. Run

#### Expected Behavior

Build and deploy successfully

#### Actual Behavior

Gives the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0010:  Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_29.apk
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_29.apk
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:486)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1075)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:169)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22021)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4876)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4128)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_29.apk
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1597)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1582)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:479)
    ... 10 more
at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 187
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 203
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 478
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__110.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 355
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<EnsureCorrectSharedRuntimes>d__107.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 266
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__106.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 194
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__104.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 119          0
```

#### Basic Information

- Version with issue: Xamarin.forms 4.6.0.772 android 10
- Last known good version: Xamarin.forms 4.6.0.772 android 9
- IDE: Visual studio 2019 v16.5.4
- Platform Target Frameworks: Android 10 (Q)

  - iOS:  8.0 (not the issue)
  - Android: 10.0
  - UWP: Windows 10 1903 18362 (not the issue)
- Android Support Library Version:
- Nuget Packages:
- Affected Devices:

#### Screenshots

[Image of error](https://ibb.co/68DR0Y7)

#### Reproduction Link

[Public git of error](https://github.com/Rikudouensof/NaijEmer)

#### Workaround

Still stuck (15-04-2020 14:11 GMT +1)

Comment: Did you change compile version to 10 and updated all Nugets?

Comment: Yes, I did, I updated it to the latest version I could find.

Comment: I wasnt able to reproduce but `android:targetSdkVersion="28"` it has to be 29

Comment: Ok. Even at 29, still same problemz

Comment: I am having the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382744/xamarin-fails-to-deploy-on-android-unexpected-install-output-error-failed-to).
Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I have. I got the answer straight from a good guy on git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem. A good fella helped me resolve it.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10707#issuecomment-630271548

I had to delete the all files generated at %localappdata%. In my windows.

Check out the link to see exact details